# Mac OS X diff tool for Microsoft Word docs?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, svn, diff

I am using svn for version control and want to be able to compare 2 revisions of a MS Word doc side-by-side.  I am aware of Araxis Merge but this converts the doc to text and compares which is more clever than I need it to be.  I would like a tool that would allow me to visually compare the files preserving the formatting, images, etc. that may be present in the doc.

I know MS Word has a compare docs feature using track changes but this requires 2 copies of the document to be present on your drive.  I want to directly compare revisions in the svn repository db without having to revert my local copy, change the filename and then compare to another working copy.

Is there any tool (free or commercial) that can do this?

Answer (score 2):

I asked another question on diffing (comparing) files a while back. You might pick some recommendations of from here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075708/diff-utility-works-for-2-files-how-to-compare-more-than-2-files-at-a-time

Wikipedia always helps as well:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools

For regular work though i usually end up using vimdiff (and there is a vim for mac). All you do to vimdiff (up to 4 default) files is vim -d file1 file2 file3 or gvim -d file1 file2 file3

Answer (score 1):

just svn export the older file elsewhere and then use the M$ Compare Changes tool.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a tool in applescript for using MS Word for diffing word files:

```
on run (arguments)
    set old to first item of arguments as string
    set new to second item of arguments as string
    tell application "Microsoft Word"
        activate
        open old
        compare active document path new as text
    end tell
end run
```

This can be run as following `osascript <path to script> old.docx new.docx`, or added as difftool in your .gitconfig `osascript <path to script> $LOCAL $REMOTE`. I use it together with Sourcetree. The only problem is having to grant access to all of the three temporary files

I expanded the script to send the files to the appropriate tool based on filetype. At the moment, I use Word for .docx and kdiff3 for other files, and this could be expanded to other tools as well.

```
on run (arguments)
    set a to first item of arguments as string
    set b to second item of arguments as string
    if {a ends with ".docx" or a ends with ".doc"} then
        diff({a, b})
    else
        do shell script "/usr/local/bin/kdiff3 " & a & " " & b
    end if
end run


on diff(arguments)
    set old to first item of arguments as string
    set new to second item of arguments as string
    tell application "Microsoft Word"
        activate
        open old
        compare active document path new as text
    end tell
end diff
```

I know I might be 10 years late, but was struggling to find a solution, so hopefully this will be helpfull to someone.

Answer (score 0):

How are you interacting with your svn repository?

I use [Versions.app](http://versionsapp.com/) to interact, and it provides a nice way of comparing files via Xcode's FileMerge utility.

Admittedly, it doesn't handle 2007-2008 files at all (*.docx) but it can do basic comparisons between files saved in the *.doc format. (Unfortunately, all the 'back-end' information is displayed too, since the files aren't ASCII.

I think that any OS X tool you use will be reliant upon the tools inside Xcode - and thus, limited to ascii files. Let me know if you find differently though!

Answer (score 0):

Try just getting two revisions together from the repository, then use Word to compare them.

In the Windows version of Word, this could be even configured into TortoiseSVN - you could select 2 versions of a DOC file to be compared, and Tortoise would open Word in a ready compare mode. I guess it was done via OLE or a command line switch.

In the Mac word, I know of no comparable thing but if it's an occasional need, you should be able to get by "manually".